# ./pingscript.sh - Georgia Weidmann's Book

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a bash script from Georgia Wiedmann's book. I have my XP target machine and my Kali machine up and running.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
echo "Usage: ./pingscript.sh [network]"
echo "example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.x.x"
else
for x in 'seq 1 254'; do
ping -c 1 $1.$x | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d" " -f4 | sed 's/.$//'
done
fi
```

I don't know whether the `8.8.8.8` should be my XP's IP or Gateway address but when I do `./pingscript.sh 192.168.x.x` I should be getting a response but it instead says `Ping unknown host`.

Anyone help?

Comment: You want backquotes, not single quotes, around `seq 1 254`, although `for x in $(seq 1 254)` is equivalent and preferable.

Comment: Above code is at page 78 of Georgia's book and the correct line for example usage is : `echo "example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.20"`, and this is why `ping -c1 $1.$x` will work .

Answer (score 5):

Here's [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net):

```
Line 7:
for x in 'seq 1 254'; do
         ^-- SC2041: This is a literal string. To run as a command, use $(..) instead of '..' .
```

Quoting its [wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2041):

> The intent was to run the code in the single quotes. This would have worked with slanted backticks, `` `..` ``, but here the very similar looking single quotes `'..'` were used, resulting in a string literal instead of command output.
>
> This is one of the many problems with backticks, so it's better to use `$(..)` to expand commands.

In other words, use:

```
for x in $(seq 1 254); do
```

Comment: Now it pings "unknown hosts" from over a certain number range. I'm using a wired connection. It should be saying 192.168.x.x: over and over again. Why is it saying: unknown hosts? Also, do I use the Gateway of the XP target or the IP address?

Comment: @wurmh0le The "example" of how to use the script is wrong; you need to supply only the first three octets (numbers from 0 to 255) of the network you want to scan; something like `./pingscript.sh 192.168.0` -- note that "x" is not a valid octet, just a placeholder. And 192.168.0 is probably not the network you're interested in either, you need to figure out the actual network number you're interested in.